# To whoever wills ... Vs. To whomever wills

Tags: syntactic-analysis, whoever-vs-whomever, prepositional-objects, objective-case

So, is it "whoever" because it is the subject of the predicate "wills", or is it "whomever" because it is the object of the preposition "to"?

Comment: The object of the preposition is **not** the word that follows *to*. It is the entire clause.

Answer (score 4):

Make whoever/whomever agree with the verb. Would you say "who wills", or "whom wills"? It's no different than "she wills" versus "her wills". Clearly we want a subject "who" and not an object "whom" here: who wills. So: to whoever wills...

There are few cases in which "whomever" is correct, but I disagree with those who would dump it altogether.

Comment: Agreed. I will utter that word to whomever I choose. In general, across various languages, the case of the relative pronoun is determined by its syntactic role within the relative clause.